# jQuery UI: draggable on dragenter

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop

I am following [this guide](http://www.elated.com/articles/drag-and-drop-with-jquery-your-essential-guide/) for jQuery draggable item.

The only thing I miss is `dragenter` and `dragleave` events to play around with CSS of interim elements. It only provides `hoverClass` property for droppable elements, when draggable elements are moved on them. How about if we need to change the CSS of other elements?

Current code look like this:

```
$(".part").draggable({
    start: startDrag,
    stop: stopDrag,
    revert: true
});
$(".parts-action").droppable({
    accept: '.part',
    hoverClass: 'hovered',
    drop: handleDrop
});
```

In addition to that, I need something like:

```
$(".wrapper").on('dragenter', function (e) {
    $(this).next(".parts-action").show();
});

$(".wrapper").on('dragleave', function (e) {
    $(this).next(".parts-action").hide();
});
```

But its not working when using `draggable()` alongside.

I also tried:

```
$(".part").draggable({
    drag: handleDrag
})

function handleDrag(e, ui){
    /* how to know if active draggable is on some element other than droppable? */
}
```

which is very confusing because its tied to draggable and droppable!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure I exactly understood your question and what you need to do, but if you need to change the css of other elements then you can use the `over` and `out` event handlers. Take a look at the [jQueryUI documentation for Droppable](http://api.jqueryui.com/droppable/#event-out). You basically want to add a class when the `over` event fires, and remove the class when the `out` event fires.

[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/KsNN7/1/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="ui-widget-content part">
  <p>Drag me to my target</p>
</div>

<div class="ui-widget-header parts-action">
  <p>Droppable area 1</p>
</div>

<div class="ui-widget-header parts-action">
  <p>Droppable area 2</p>
</div>

<div class="ui-widget-header parts-action">
  <p>Droppable area 3</p>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.parts-action { width: 150px; height: 150px; padding: 0.5em; float: left; margin: 10px; }    
.part { width: 100px; height: 100px; padding: 0.5em; float: left; margin: 10px 10px 10px 0; }    
.parts-action-highlight { background: red; }
```

**jQuery**

```
$(function() {
    $( ".part" ).draggable();
    $( ".parts-action" ).droppable({
        accept: ".part",
        hoverClass: "ui-state-active",
        drop: function( event, ui ) {
            $(this)
              .addClass( "ui-state-highlight" )
              .find( "p" )
              .html( "Dropped!" );
        },
        over: function( event, ui ) {
            $(this)
               .siblings(".parts-action")
               .addClass("parts-action-highlight");
        },
        out: function( event, ui ) {
            $(this)
              .siblings(".parts-action")
              .removeClass("parts-action-highlight");
        }
    });
});
```

Most of the above code sample is taken from the jQueryUI droppabe samples so the ui-widget-XXX classes are not required/relevant to you, just left in to highlight the effect.

Just replace the body of the function call with whatever action you need to take, e.g.

```
        over: function( event, ui ) {
            $(this)
               .siblings(".parts-action")
               .hide();
        },
        out: function( event, ui ) {
            $(this)
              .siblings(".parts-action")
              .show();
```

Comment: You will need to define 2 droppable areas, the first one will trigger the show hide of the second, and also a container to figure out when you leave the entire again to hide the 2nd drop. Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/KsNN7/3/

Comment: +1, Thank you. But the behavior in my case is very inconsistent, when I open in Chrome. Can you please take a look at my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jvGuQ/. By the time the mouse is moved over "Drag child" div, it disappears. The console logs suggest that the handleDrop is fired when the item is on info div. Also, the hidden fields are not appearing on root nodes (A, B, C, D) unless draggable is moved to the left of the item. Can you please take a look where I am making a mistake.

Comment: Very strange, will see if I can figure out what's going on. Assume you want [this behaviour](http://www.htmldrive.net/items/demo/721/JQuery-Draggable-Sitemap)? Maybe rather than drop area, you could highlight which nodes are valid drop areas (with green border) or invalid (with red border/text strikethrough)?

Comment: Actually we have two options, either we can add as a sibling or child. I have improved the script. http://jsfiddle.net/7cQLz/. If the draggable item has children, it doesn't trigger the droppable we target but the other one.

Comment: Surely adding as a sibling is the same thing as adding as a child of the parent item?

Comment: i haven't implemented dropping child logic yet. But it would add to next level (with a constraint; the tree level shouldn't exceed 3).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30721/discussion-between-jammykam-and-annie)